# What is the best way to use the OpenCV library in conjunction with the Armadillo library?

Tags: opencv, armadillo

I am building an image processing application using OpenCV. I am also using the Armadillo library because it has some very neat matrix related functions. The thing is though, in order to use Armadillo functions on cv::Mat I need frequent conversions from cv::Mat to arma::Mat .
To accomplish this I convert the cv::Mat to an arma::Mat using a function like this

```
arma::Mat cvMat2armaMat(cv::Mat M)
{
    copy cv::Mat data to a arma::Mat
    return arma::Mat
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid or reduce copying, you can access the memory used by Armadillo matrices via the [.memptr()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#memptr) member function. For example:

```
mat X(5,6);
double* mem = X.memptr();
```

Be careful when using the above, as you're not allowed to free the memory yourself (Armadillo will still manage the memory).

Alternatively, you can construct an Armadillo matrix [directly](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat) from existing memory.  For example:

```
double* data = new double[4*5];
// ... fill data ...
mat X(data, 4, 5, false);  // 'false' indicates that no copying is to be done; see docs
```

In this case you will be responsible for manually managing the memory.

Also bear in mind that Armadillo stores and accesses matrices in [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_major#Column-major_order), ie. column 0 is first stored, then column 1, column 2, etc. This is the same as used by MATLAB, LAPACK and BLAS.

Comment: This is finally what I came up with...   `template<class T3>
arma::Mat<T3> cvMat2armaMat(cv::Mat cvMatIn)
{  
 arma::Mat<T3> armaConv(cvMatIn.data, cvMatIn.rows, cvMatIn.cols,false); 
 return armaConv;
}`

Comment: I don't think your code will be reliable and/or efficient. The code is passing the cvMatIn matrix by value, which is implicitly making a temporary copy inside the function. It is then creating an Armadillo matrix directly from existing memory of the temporary. If the C++ compiler is using Return Value Optimisation (RVO), the code will be broken as the temporary gets destroyed, and hence the memory would no longer be valid. If the compiler isn't using RVO, it is in effect making _another_ Armadillo matrix on return, by copying the freshly created one.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the object passed as cvMatIn will live as long as the created Armadillo matrix, code along the following lines would be better: template<class T> inline void cvMat2armaMat(const cv::Mat& cvMatIn) { return arma::Mat<T>(cvMatIn.data, cvMatIn.rows, cvMatIn.cols, false); }.  If you can't make the guarantee, omit the last "false", ie: { return arma::Mat<T>(cvMatIn.data, cvMatIn.rows, cvMatIn.cols); }. In both cases you still need to take into account that Armadillo uses column-major order, ie. the matrix elements will be transposed if cvMatIn is using row-major order.

Comment: small mistake in my comment: change "void" to arma::Mat<T>

Comment: Hey thanks for the follow up comments. Yeah, I'll change the function to take in values by reference. Also, mostly the original matrix will outlive the armadillo matrix. So copying it with'false' should be fine. But I may end up creating two different versions of the function to handle the two cases.